# How do I split a line down further in Python txt files?

Tags: python, file, split, file-handling, txt

I am trying to split a line down into smaller elements

Each line contains the birds' name and the number of times it has been seen. I am trying to display them both if the name matches but I can't find a way to split one line down further.

Here's my code:

```
with open("birdFile.txt", "w") as file:
numRecs = int(input("How many records do you wish to write? "))
for n in range(1,numRecs+1):
  birdName = input("Enter bird name: ")
  birdsReported = input("Enter number of bird reported: ")
  file.write(birdName + birdsReported + ",")

with open("birdFile.txt", "r") as file:
  birdNameSearch = input("What bird are you searching for? ")
  for line in file:
    file = line.split(",")
    birdName = line[0]
    birdsSeen = line[1]
    if birdNameSearch == birdName:
      print(birdName + ": " + birdsSeen)
```

Comment: `file.write(birdName + "," + birdsReported + "\n")`

Answer (score 0):

You wrote

```
  file.write(birdName + birdsReported + ",")
```

Notice that the `,` comma came after the number -- you want it
before, to separate name from number.

---

Also, you'll want a `\n` newline at end of line.
This is most conveniently accomplished with an f-string:

```
  file.write(f'{birdName},{birdsReported}\n')
```

---

Consider using the csv module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html